# android change cursor position in cursor adapter to increse or decrease rows

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, cursor-position, android-cursoradapter

I need to implement `CursorAdapter`, where i need to filter out certain rows at a time.

For ex: first showing 1-5, then 5-10.

I have managed `getCount()` as per it, but just by changing cursor position it is not working.

I need to know how these rows get the position, or how to advance the cursor that is provided as parameter in `newView()` and `bindView()`.

P.S: I know about `limit` and `paging` and `offset`, but not want to fetch query every time

Comment: you will probably want to implement a paging so better use limit, offset perhaps but here's a better ideas http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ScrollingCursor

Comment: yes i need to do this only, but not want to fetch query every time.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey in your adapter override these methods as below. You can change the page by changing the presentPage and notifiy the adpater

```
 int numOfItemsPerPage=5,presentPage=0;
 public int getCount() {
   return (list.size()>= numOfItemsPerPage) ?list.size():numOfItemsPerPage;
 }

 public Object getItem(int position) {
       if(list.size()>= numOfItemsPerPage)
       {
          position= (numOfItemsPerPage * presentPage)+position;
       }
       return list.get(position);
 }
```